# How to tackle this tricky recoding of a response variable in R

Tags: r, for-loop, recode

I'm trying to recode a variable that was not coded correctly upon data entry. It's (seemingly) tricky, and I could use a bit of direction.

The data frame (in long format) has three columns: **s_id** (participant identifier); **i_id** (item identifier); **score** (binary--0/1--correct/incorrect). It's **score** that needs to be recoded.

This assessment was such that for each participant, items were administered **until 6 consecutive items were answered incorrectly** (call the 6th incorrect item the *basal* item). At this point, **14 additional items were administered**, and all remaining items after the 14 should have been coded as missing. The problem is that all items after the 14 were coded with zeros, which makes analysis difficult.

I need a new variable **n_score**, created by cycling through each participant's original scores, looking for the first instance of six consecutive 0's, count 14 more after that. These scores are simply placed in n_score, but what comes after for each participant should be recoded `NA`.

I'm in a for-loop hell, and could use some help--perhaps a clever way to tackle the problem. Below is a reproducible example of the data structure, with an added column (n_score), which is what the newly recoded variable should look like.

To generate data:

```
s_id <- rep(c(1:2), each = 25)
i_id <- rep(1:25, 2)
score <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,
           1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)
n_score <- c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,
             1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA)

dat <- data.frame(
  s_id = s_id,
  i_id = i_id,
  score = score,
  n_score = n_score
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code gives the same output than in n_score:

```
mypattern = '000000'
recode <- function(x) {
  start <- regexpr(mypattern, paste(x,collapse=''))
  end <- start + 6 + 14 -1
  return(c(x[1:end], rep(NA, length(x) - end)))
}

ddply(dat, .(s_id), transform, newcol=recode(score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in base R that splits the data by `s_id`; looks for runs of 6 or more zeros in `score` in the resulting data frames; uses the position of those runs' ends plus 14 to flip score to `NA`; then binds the results back together into one data frame.

```
newdat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$s_id), function(i) {

    x <- rle(i$score)

    i$n_score <- ifelse(seq_along(i$score) > sum(x$lengths[1:which(x$lengths >= 6 & x$values == 0)]) + 14, NA, i$score)

    return(i)

}))
```

Result:

```
> newdat
     s_id i_id score n_score
1.1     1    1     1       1
1.2     1    2     1       1
1.3     1    3     0       0
1.4     1    4     0       0
1.5     1    5     0       0
1.6     1    6     0       0
1.7     1    7     0       0
1.8     1    8     0       0
1.9     1    9     1       1
1.10    1   10     0       0
1.11    1   11     1       1
1.12    1   12     0       0
1.13    1   13     0       0
1.14    1   14     0       0
1.15    1   15     1       1
1.16    1   16     1       1
1.17    1   17     0       0
1.18    1   18     0       0
1.19    1   19     1       1
1.20    1   20     0       0
1.21    1   21     0       0
1.22    1   22     0       0
1.23    1   23     1      NA
1.24    1   24     1      NA
1.25    1   25     1      NA
2.26    2    1     1       1
2.27    2    2     1       1
2.28    2    3     0       0
2.29    2    4     0       0
2.30    2    5     0       0
2.31    2    6     0       0
2.32    2    7     0       0
2.33    2    8     0       0
2.34    2    9     1       1
2.35    2   10     0       0
2.36    2   11     1       1
2.37    2   12     0       0
2.38    2   13     0       0
2.39    2   14     0       0
2.40    2   15     1       1
2.41    2   16     1       1
2.42    2   17     0       0
2.43    2   18     0       0
2.44    2   19     1       1
2.45    2   20     0       0
2.46    2   21     0       0
2.47    2   22     0       0
2.48    2   23     1      NA
2.49    2   24     1      NA
2.50    2   25     1      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is efficient or not, but here's my attempt:

```
dat$New_n_score <- NA

SixZeros <- rep(0, 6)
m <- length(SixZeros)


for(j in unique(dat$s_id)){

  score <- dat$score[dat$s_id == j]

  n <- length(score)
  ind <- seq.int(length = n - m + 1)
  pos <- rep(TRUE, times = n - m + 1)

  for (i in seq.int(length = m)) {
    pos <- pos & (SixZeros[i] == score[ind + i - 1])
  }

  n_score_stop <- which(pos) + 19 

  dat$New_n_score[dat$s_id == j][1:n_score_stop] <- dat$score[dat$s_id == j][1:n_score_stop]

}
```